# Office 365 reports data inconstency

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We're encountering data consistency issues with the Office 365 reports, from the Office 365 admin center or using the Microsoft Graph reports API.
The data is not consistent when we compare "Activity" on a period and "Details" on a day. Here's an example with the Skype activity but it is reproductible with all other 'tools' (exchange, SP, ..).

Example from the Office 365 admin center :

- Here is our tenant Activity for the past 30 days. If I select July 21 in the chart, i can see there has been 38 peer to peer sessions in my tenant.
- Now, if I click this point in the chart, activity details for this single day is displayed. As you can see, data is not consistent at all with the data from the "main" Activity chart.

[IMAGE: 30 days activity vs single day activity details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XghZC.png)

We're encountering the exact same issue with the API (sfbactivity. Data is not consistent between Activity/D30 and Details/date=21/07/2017).

We have an Office 365 account, but it seems that we are a "too small company" to be allowed to create a ticket in the Support center.

Does anyone noticed the same issue with their data ?

Can anybody from Microsoft help us to create a support ticket somewhere so we can know if this is an already identified issue, and when it's going to be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed now. The full list of daily active users are included in the user grid and exported file. Sorry for the inconvenience.